# Dagger 2 generated test component not recognized

Tags: java, android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm hoping that this is just something I'm doing wrong here.  I'm trying to use Dagger 2.0 to inject dependencies for my JUnit tests (*not Espresso tests*, just pure JUnit).  So, I have a 'main' java module and a 'test' java module.  In the main module, I've got a Dagger Module and a Component:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {
    @Provides
    public Widget provideWidget() {
        return new ConcreteWidget();
    }
}

...

@Component (modules = MainModule.class)
public interface MainComponent {
    void inject(WidgetConsumer consumer);
}
```

And in my test module, I have the following:

```
@Module
public class TestModule {
    @Provides public Widget provideWidget() {
        return new Widget() {
            @Override
            public void doThing() {
                int y = 6;
                y ++;
            }
        };
    }
}

...

@Component(modules = TestModule.class)
public interface TestComponent extends MainComponent{
}
```

My build.gradle has dependencies that look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'

    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'
}
```

For whatever reason, Dagger generates `DaggerMainComponent`, but refuses to generate `DaggerTestComponent`.  There appear to be no errors in the gradle output when I build.

Here's the thing... I think the annotation processor is running, but somehow the android gradle plugin is failing to pull in those generated sources during compile-time.  I have inspected the app/build/generated/source/apt/test/ directory and found `DaggerTestComponent.java` in there, but for some reason, it's not imported as a dependency.

Any thoughts?  [Here is a link to a test project showing my issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kf6rhv8vyzcyn0/daggertest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Please post a test project if possible.

Comment: Sure thing.  Edited my response to add a link to a test project.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add this to `build.gradle` after `android` DSL:

```
android {
    ...
}

android.applicationVariants.all {
    def aptOutputDir = new File(buildDir, "generated/source/apt/${it.unitTestVariant.dirName}")
    it.unitTestVariant.addJavaSourceFoldersToModel(aptOutputDir)
}
```

Thereafter, your test component would be recognized.

For Kotlin replace `generated/source/apt/...` with `generated/source/kapt/...`

There is [an issue raised](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224272) in the tracker concerning this.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but I'm having trouble with it.  Is there anywhere I can examine the DSL syntax?  It's telling me that `applicationVariants` doesn't exist in android.  I have a feeling they either renamed it, got rid of it, or moved it somewhere else.  `android.buildTypes` and `android.sourceSets` exists, but `android.applicationVariants` doesn't seem to (with gradle plugin v 2.3.0-rc1).

Comment: I've just made one change in the source code you provided. I've only added those three lines after `android {}` in `build.gradle`. Check it out.

Comment: Yeah, I tried exactly that (after the android block).  I get "Could not get unknown property 'applicationVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension."  Ah! I think I know what my issue is... I'm using `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` at the top.  Sorry, I posted an example project here and am trying to apply this fix to my actual project, which is an android library (AAR) project.  I bet libraries don't have variants or something.  How would this look for a library project, do you know?

Comment: Nevermind, it's `libraryVariants`.  Figured it out.  Tested your fix and it works perfectly, thanks!  Can't wait until Google fixes their plugin though, we really shouldn't have to do this...

Comment: I was recking my brain with this for last few hours. Finally found workaround that works. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to do this in the pure Java / Intellij Idea case? If so please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759253/how-do-you-define-dagger-components-and-modules-in-tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround, just in case anybody gets stuck with this issue in the future.  It appears the `testAnnotationProcessor` command in the android gradle plugin does not work for test modules (possibly a bug in their implementation?).  So you can write `testAnnotationProcessor` and your build.gradle will compile but it seems to not work properly.

The workaround is to fall back to the older third-party annotation processing plugin by Hugo Visser (android-apt).

To do that, add the following to your buildscript dependencies in your main build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-rc1'

        // ADD THIS LINE HERE vvv
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

Then, in your individual module's build.gradle, add the following line at the top:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

// ADD THIS LINE HERE vvv
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Finally, instead of using `testAnnotationProcessor` and `annotationProcessor`, just use `apt` and `testApt`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
    // USE apt INSTEAD OF annotationProcessor HERE vvv
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

    testCompile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
    // USE testApt INSTEAD OF testAnnotationProcessor HERE vvv
    testApt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Note that you must use the 1.8 version of android-apt, as the 1.4 version does not ship with the `testApt` command/function/whatever.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work anymore (working with Gradle 3.1.0) --> Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your test type:

- insert `testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x"` inside dependencies on your build.gradle file for `src/test`

or

- insert `androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x"` inside dependencies on your build.gradle file for `src/androidTest`