# Cannot find symbol variable DaggerTestComponent

Tags: android, dagger-2

Im trying to inject my App Component [like this](https://github.com/ribot/ribot-app-android/blob/master/app/src/commonTest/java/io/ribot/app/test/common/TestComponentRule.java)
because Im using this boilerplate.

```
private void setupDaggerTestComponentInApplication() {
    WSApplication application = WSApplication.get(mContext);
    mTestComponent = DaggerTestComponent.builder()
            .applicationTestModule(new ApplicationTestModule(application))
            .build();
    application.setComponent(mTestComponent);
}
```

This is located in a new testing folder:

```
sourceSets {
    def commonTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
    test {
        java.srcDir commonTestDir
    }
    androidTest {
        java.srcDir commonTestDir
    }
}

DAGGER_VERSION = '2.11-rc2'
```

Output:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerTestComponent
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dagger 2 generated test component not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793505/dagger-2-generated-test-component-not-recognized)

Comment: whats is {it.unitTestVariant.dirName}?, im just  using java without testing in this folder

Comment: Thank you but It didnt solved my problem